# CSS: responsive grid/flex layout when there are intermediate divs between the parent and children?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, responsive, css-grid

So suppose I have the following HTML structure. Is there anyway I can create a responsive 'grid' type layout directly with CSS, without having to use Javascript to edit the DOM structure? As you can see by running the example, each `row` is displayed on a new row visually - what I would want, for example, is let's say the screen is wide enough to display 3 `p` elements, then that would mean that the 'visual' row display to the user would be `p` elements 1, 2 & 3 on row 1 (despite that fact that element 1 & 2 are in a different `row` class than element 3), then `p` elements 4, 5, 6 being on row 2 etc etc

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #555;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>6</p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    <p>18</p>
    <p>19</p>
    <p>20</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think it should be obvious what I am trying to achieve, but I know for myself, I find it much easier to visualise the desired result, rather than trying to understand what is desired from a description...so here is what I am trying to go for:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

.group{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #666;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='group'>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    <p>18</p>
    <p>19</p>
    <p>20</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I'm wondering, is there any way I could achieve this purely in CSS? Thanks!

Comment: use `display:contents` with .row

Comment: @TemaniAfif lol, so simple. I had no idea. If you care about points or anything, you can make this comment as an answer and I will accept it as the best answer

Comment: I already gave the same answer in another question so I have closed as duplicate